# Zero-initialissation of a variable of class type having a base class with a user-supplied constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Given the following code snippet:

```
struct A
{
  int x,y;
  A() : x(0), y(0) {};
};

struct B : A
{
  int z;
};

int main()
{
  B b1 = B(); // is b1 zero-initialised?
  B b2{}; // is b2 zero-initialised?
  return 0;
}
```

Are b1 and/or b2 zero-initialised (via value initialisation) or not?

I'm especially confused about `b1`. What I expect to happen is that the temporary object `B()` is value-initialised, resulting it to be zero-initialised. But I'm not really sure if `struct B` fits the rules for zero-initialisation. It all seems to depend on whether the default-constructor of `B` is  user provided or non-trivial.

I'm *guessing* that `B` has a non-user-provided non-trivial default constructor, which would result in `b1` being default-initialised. Am I correct?

Comment: `B b1 = B();` is doing [*copy initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) of a [*value initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) object. While `B b2{};` is doing [value initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Value initialization could leads to "zero initialization".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OK, so both the values of `b1` and `b2` end up with a *value initialised* value. But is this value *zero initialised* in this specific case?

Comment: Quoting from the value-initialization links: "if T is a class type with a default constructor that is neither user-provided nor deleted (that is, it may be a class with an implicitly-defined or defaulted default constructor), the object is zero-initialized" This seems to fit the `B` class so yes it will be ["zero-initialized"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for clarifying. Very much appreciated.